# How to Convert distorted points to undistorted points?

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, photogrammetry

[Distorted image from camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M3uM.jpg)

We have a distorted image from the camera.

We were trying to undistort the image, which was partially solved by calculating the
calibration data -> **calibration matrix** & **distortion coefficients**; & putting the same in cv2's undistort function.

***Steps for calibration:***

```
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, CHECKERBOARD, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11,11),(-1,-1), criteria)
imgpoints.append(corners2)
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
```

***Steps for undistortion of image:***

```
undistorted_img = cv2.undistort(src=img,
                                cameraMatrix=np.array(
                                        calibration_params["calibration_matrix"]),
                                distCoeffs=np.array(
                                        calibration_params["dist"])
                               )
```

***Steps to find undistorted points:***

```
undistorted_points = cv2.undistortPointsIter(src=(x_, y_),
                                             cameraMatrix=np.array(
                                                 calibration_params["calibration_matrix"]),
                                             distCoeffs=np.array(
                                                 calibration_params["dist"]),
                                             R=np.eye(3, dtype=np.float64),
                                             P = np.array(
                                                 calibration_params["calibration_matrix"]),
                                             criteria=criteria
                                            )
```

[Undistorted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb0vH.jpg)

When plotted as shown in the image, the 2 outputs are quite different.
I have also tried using camera matrix in distort image, but still no

Comment: I have a working example for fishey model. I guess the same function is available for normal lens model: 
`cv::fisheye::undistortPoints(points, result, intrinsicCameraMatrix_distorted, intrinsicDistortionCoefficients, rectification_information, intrinsicCameraMatrix_corrected);` The second camera matrix (corrected) is computed by `cv::fisheye::estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify` I think you have to do this as well (with standard model instead of fisheye). Or maybe you get this form calibrateCamera call if you dont set none there.

Comment: @Micka We are using wide angle camera, not fisheye. cv2 doesn't have `estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify` equivalent for normal camera. Instead I used `getOptimalNewCameraMatrix`, but the results were not as desired.